# Pallet session: What is the purpose of the `proof` argument on the `set_keys` extrinsic?

Tags: pallet, extrinsic, key

The `set_keys` extrinsic in `pallet_session` has a second argument [`proof`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/074dc1dfee4132b597db6eb147a86c72b751f03c/frame/session/src/lib.rs#L588), which seems to be intended as an ownership proof of the `keys`.

Looking at the body, there is a call to [`ownership_proof_is_valid`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/074dc1dfee4132b597db6eb147a86c72b751f03c/frame/session/src/lib.rs#L590).

The `ownership_proof_is_valid` method is defined on the [`OpaqueKeys`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/074dc1dfee4132b597db6eb147a86c72b751f03c/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs#L1724-L1725) trait, with a default implementation that just returns `true`.

The intended way to implement `OpaqueKeys` is, as far as I know, to use the [`impl_opaque_keys` macro](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/074dc1dfee4132b597db6eb147a86c72b751f03c/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs#L2047). That macro, however generates an implementation that does not [override the default implementation of `ownership_proof_is_valid`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/074dc1dfee4132b597db6eb147a86c72b751f03c/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs#L1990-L2018).

It seems to me, then, that in practice `ownership_proof_is_valid` will always return `true`. If that's the case, what is the purpose of the `proof` argument?

Comment: I'm not sure. When running this extrinsic manually, I always put `0x00` as proof and it works. Also see: https://docs.peaq.network/docs/node-operators/become-collator/generate-session-key/#generate-the-key

Answer (score 0):

It looks like dead code to me, and confusing API.

I opened an issue here https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/3218